# Suggestion regarding host a node.js and socket.io app in aws webserver with a config OS windows 2008 R2 and IIS 7

Tags: node.js, iis, amazon-web-services, iis-7, socket.io

I have been kept on trying to host my nodeJS and socket.io chat app on a web server with Windows 2008 R2 OS and IIS version 7.I have been kept on trying a lot of things to make it work.The problem is my nodeJS app is getting connected but not my socket.io. I have looked into lots of tutorials regarding this but everything is saying the same but nothing works out. Here is one of the link I saw http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2013/01/hosting-socketio-websocket-apps-in-iis.html

I am receiving a 404 error.

> GET http://my ip:8081/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1431071918368-3

404 Not Found
        250ms

Kindly help me out with it!!
Thanks

Comment: Phase put the relevant parts if code in the question. It's hard to answer without it

Comment: my doubt is simple can I use nodejs and socket.io create a chat app and host it in web server with the above config windows 2008 R2 and IIS v7

Comment: Yes you can, but you haven't asked a specific question

Comment: sorry I will update it..

Comment: even after I did all the web config as said in the link I had mentioned I am receiving the error

Comment: I'm trying to make it work as well I successfully installed the helloWorld app for iisnode but I can not figure it out how to use the sockets.io to recreate their chat exmaple. I get `code`